# NestJs v9 doesn't resolve my dependency eventhough it seems to be properly imported. The same project used to work in NestJs 7

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I've got a module exporting a DatabaseUserRepository :

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmConfigModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Project, User])],
  providers: [DatabaseProjectRepository, DatabaseUserRepository],
  exports: [DatabaseProjectRepository, DatabaseUserRepository], // I'm explictely exporting DatabaseProjectRepository
})
export class RepositoriesModule {}
```

And another project is trying to inject it in a custom provider :

```
@Module({
  imports: [LoggerModule, EnvironmentConfigModule, RepositoriesModule, ExceptionsModule],
})
export class ProjectUsecasesModule {
  static GET_PROJECT_USECASE = 'getProjectUsecases';

  static register(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: ProjectUsecasesModule,
      imports: [RepositoriesModule], // And here I'm importing the module containing DatabaseProjectRepository
      providers: [
        {
          inject: [DatabaseProjectRepository], 
          provide: ProjectUsecasesModule.GET_PROJECT_USECASE,
          useFactory: (ProjectRepository: DatabaseProjectRepository) => new GetProjectUseCases(ProjectRepository), // And here nest complains it cannot find DatabaseProjectRepository
        },
```

I have the following error at runtime :

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the getProjectUsecases (?). Please
> make sure that the argument DatabaseProjectRepository at index [0] is
> available in the ProjectUsecasesModule context.

This code used to work in nest v7 without needed to import the RepositoriesModule at all (which surely was not the intended behaviour either).

Does someone have any idea what would be causing my problem ?

Comment: can you show us `DatabaseUserRepository`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the issue.

Above in my file I wrote

```
import { DatabaseProjectRepository } from '../repositories/Project.repository';
```

instead of

```
import { DatabaseProjectRepository } from '../repositories/project.repository'; // i.e. lowercase project
```

The incorrect casing was not preventing my code from building, but it was somehow messing with Nest module resolution ... !

Comment: To explain _why_ it was messing with the resolution, in Nest v8 we changed from using the class name as the provider token to class references where appropriate. When having an import to the same file but with different casing, the class reference now becomes two class references and the reference to A1 is not the same as the reference to A2 [a property of JS realms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#instanceof_and_multiple_realms). When the name was just stringified it was fine because a string is a string but class references are different